# What is the best way to remove items from a IEnumerable<SelectListItem>?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have an asp.net-mvc website and i am trying to use a dual listbox plugin

I have an array of

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allItems:
```

and I have an array of Ints

```
IEnumerable<int> selectedIds;
```

that represents the Selected Value that someone filtered by.  My goal is to see if given these two imputs, I can create two IEnumerable

```
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectedItems;
 IEnumerable<SelectListItem> nonSelectedItems;
```

that I would use to populate the dual listbox plugin.  I can get the selectedItems pretty easily but when i try to create the nonselected List i try to use Except() but it doesn't seem to be able to take the full list and "subtract" any item in the selected list.

Am I using the wrong method to do this filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Where()`:

```
allItems.Where(o => !selectedIds.Contains(int.Parse(o.Value)))
```

You can compute both sublists at once using `ToLookup`:

```
var lookup = allItems.ToLookup(o => selectedIds.Contains(int.Parse(o.Value)));
var selectedItems = lookup[true];
```

You can make these much faster by changing the `IEnumerable<int>` to a `HashSet<int>` so that `Contains()` becomes O(1).  Just make sure not to [covarinatly lose that](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/12/dark-side-of-covariance.html/).